# TABS Are not displayed in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am not able to understand why the main fragment is not showing the tabs. My code does not have any errors, its just when I click a item in navigation drawer its not displaying the fragment with tabs.
Can someone please help, thanks for your time, appreciate it.

Main fragment code

```
    package app.com.navigatemenu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MainFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static MainFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
/*
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
*/
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);


        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Fragment C"),
                MovieFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Fragment B"),
                GalleryFragment.class, null);
        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Main Activity Code

```
   package app.com.navact;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        FragmentA.OnFragmentInteractionListener, FragmentB.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Fragment_main layout

```
  <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Fragment_conatiner

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

File for fragment container

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="app.com.navact.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

to

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

Please let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE YOU DO ANY OF THIS MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A BACKUP OF YOUR PROJECT AS I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS!!!**

**INSIDE COORDINATORLAYOUT**
Before the **`fragment_container`** I want you to place a **`FrameLayout`**, make sure it's **`layout_height`** is **`wrap_content`**. I want you to make it's **`id`** equal to **`realtabcontent`**. I want you to add the attribute **`layout_weight`** to **`fragment_container`** and make it equal to **`1`**.

**I want you to delete fragment main layout, MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A BACKUP OF THIS PROJECT!!!**

**INSIDE MAINFRAGMENT**

**I want you to change onCreateView to:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Fragment C"), MovieFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Fragment B"), GalleryFragment.class, null);
    return inflater.inflate(R.id.fragment_container, null);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131433/discussion-on-answer-by-blazedev-tabs-are-not-displayed-in-fragment).

Comment: SO I added this before fragment_container
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

also added your code in main fragment on create view... i ran project.... I don't see tabs, but I see text on screen "Gallery Fragment." .. looks like something worked as it called the fragment.... but no tabs...

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity

```
         package app.com.navact;
            import android.net.Uri;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
            import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
            import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
            import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
            import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.MenuItem;

            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
                    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
                    {

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    Toolbar toolbar = 

    (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                });

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();

                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    // Handle the camera action
                } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

                } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

                }

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

            }
        }
```

Main Fragment

```
        package app.com.navact;
        import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
        import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;


        /**
         * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
         * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
         * {@link MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
         * to handle interaction events.
         * Use the {@link MainFragment#newInstance} factory method to
         * create an instance of this fragment.
         */
        public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
            private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
            private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
            private String mParam1;
            private String mParam2;
            private FragmentTabHost mTabHost ;

            private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
            public static TabLayout tabLayout;
            public static ViewPager viewPager;
            public static int int_items = 2 ;

            public MainFragment() {
                // Required empty public constructor
            }

            /**
             * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
             * this fragment using the provided parameters.
             *
             * @param param1 Parameter 1.
             * @param param2 Parameter 2.
             * @return A new instance of fragment MainFragment.
             */
            // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
            public static MainFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
                MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
                args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                if (getArguments() != null) {
                    mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                    mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
                tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

                tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                    }
                });

                return x;
            }

            // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
            public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAttach(Context context) {
                super.onAttach(context);
                if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                    mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                            + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
                }
            }

            class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

                public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                    super(fm);
                }

                /**
                 * Return fragment with respect to Position .
                 */

                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position)
                {
                    switch (position){
                        case 0 : return new TabFragment1();
                        case 1 : return new TabFragment2();

                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {

                    return int_items;

                }

                /**
                 * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
                 */

                @Override
                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

                    switch (position){
                        case 0 :
                            return "TabFragMent1";
                        case 1 :
                            return "TabFragment2";

                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onDetach() {
                super.onDetach();
                mListener = null;
            }


            public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
                // TODO: Update argument type and name
                void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
            }
        }
```

Tab Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
             app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Tab Activity1

```
        package app.com.navact;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;




        public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment1, container, false);
                }

        }
```

TabActivity2

```
        package app.com.navact;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;


        public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment2, container, false);
            }
        }
```

tab1 layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:text="Primary\nFragment"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="androidbelieve.com"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:textStyle="italic"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

tab2Layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Tab 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

app build Gradle

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 25
            buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "app.com.navact"
                minSdkVersion 19
                targetSdkVersion 25
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
        }
```

Comment: took me 10 hours to reach to this solution , this is sliding tab inside the fragment , integrted with navigation drawer.... its 3am now , i am sleeping ... this is my give back to community ... cheers and merry xmas.... :)

Comment: Please don't just dump your whole project here - try to explain the solution as a [mcve]